# What is the thermal expansion equation for a cylinder (plane strain)?

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science

I know under plane stress assumption it would be dR=(alpha)*(R_0)*dT.
What about plane strain?

I tested it in Abaqus and plane strain had a higher radial displacement than plane stress assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really straightforward problem.  It is the linear superposition of two problems:  first (a) thermal expansion with plane stress followed by (b) axial compression to remove the axial strain from step (a).  The radial strain ratio of plane stress to plane strain is then $(1+\nu)$, where $\nu$ is the Poisson ratio.

Comment: Is this the same for a solid cylinder without a bore

Comment: How did a cylinder with a bore get into this discussion?